# Using IZWebFileManager server control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controls, webforms, web-controls

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 3 project and need to use IZWebFileManager there. This is ASP.net server control and it works well in WebForms. Even if i include 1 webform in mvc project. But how to use it in Views of MVC? adding runat="server" to head of the page and adding form that runat="server" dont help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IZWebFileManager is designed as ASP.NET WebForms control and uses CallBack feature of ASP.NET 2.0.

Such design does not support ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. I now try to place this control into the simple WebForm.aspx page and load it into <iframe> on mvc viewpage. Works pretty well! Great control!